# how to increment counter variable in side for loop in XPATh query using oracle

Tags: oracle, xpath

I have for loop in XPath query and want to declare one more counter variable inside it and increment by one for each iteration:

```
XMLQUERY('
let $parts := $empCntnt/employee/part
let $cntr :=0
for $part in $parts
 let $partName := string($part/@id)
 $cntr =$cntr +1
return concat($partName, $cntr)
' PASSING emp_cntnt AS "empCntnt" RETURNING CONTENT).getStringVal()
```

Answer (score 0):

XQuery is a functional language so variables are immutable.

Try

```
for $part at $cntr in $parts....
```

Alternatively process the sequence using a recursive function.